# How to use cmake -v invocation to help find linker error

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I get the following error from my android studio NDK build:

```
Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I "use -v to see invocation" as error suggests?

I tried adding "-v" to my build.gradle cppflags as such:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags "-v -std=c++11 -fexceptions"
    }
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi', 'mips'
    }
}
```

I did not see any change with this.

I saw this elsewhere, but not sure it helps either.

```
arguments "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON"
```

The origin of the problem is in an include file that is included by many other files. The file works fine, but when I add a std::string const initialized in cpp - I get the error.

I am trying to figure out why the addition of this line generates a cmake multiple definition error.

Comment: don't you want to set -v on the linker flags rather than the cxx flags?

Comment: to pass **`-l`** to linker, you can add `-Wl,-l` to **cppFlags**.

Comment: Looks like suggestion about `-v` option is printed by ninja tool and relates to it rather than to linker. BTW complete compiler / linker command lines may be found in `build.ninja`, `rules.ninja` files under `<your_module>/.externalNativeBuild` hierarchy.

Comment: @Alex: I tried -l in cppflags it resulted in error, but -WL works.

Comment: @Sergio yes, I think you are right. Thanks.