# How to use -v invocation to see details on cmake linker error (undefined symbols)?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

How specifically do I use the -v invocation to see details on a cmake linker error? I found two existing questions about using this option, but one is for Xcode builds and the other for NDK builds.  They are here:

[use -v to see invocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48247294/use-v-to-see-invocation)

[How to use cmake -v invocation to help find linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504430/how-to-use-cmake-v-invocation-to-help-find-linker-error)

I am on OSX Mojave. I am using a standard cmakelists.txt approach, and the error is this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "Image::createImage(int, int, int)", referenced from:
       _main in tutorial.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

A comment in a SO question shows what I am trying to do:

```
...you could use -v to see the linker invocation to see what's going wrong. It would show you this link line:

"/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 
    -macosx_version_min 10.6.8 -o a.out -lcrt1.10.6.o
    /var/folders/zl/zlZcj24WHvenScwjPFFFQE+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-hdOL8Z.o
    -lSystem /Developer/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

(I'm a cmake rookie btw) I have tried all of the following in my cmakelists.txt but they did not work:

```
add_link_options(-v)
add_link_options("-v")
target_link_options(myexec PUBLIC -v)
target_link_options(myexec PUBLIC "-v")
target_link_options(myexec PUBLIC "LINKER:-v")
```

Comment: What version of CMAKE do you have? `add_link_options` & `target_link_options` were added in CMAKE 3.13.

Comment: I'm using CMAKE 3.15.3.  Yes, it seems I must be using add_link_options and target_link_options wrongly.

Comment: Have you tried `add_link_options("LINKER:-v")`? According to the CMAKE documentation( https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_link_options.html ), if your CMAKE setup uses the compiler(`gcc`/`clang`) to link stuff, you would need to do that. Also, I would check for missing libraries, 32 bit libraries, or anything being compiled 32 bit.

Comment: Tried it but the output is exactly the same as without trying it.  I used exactly what you recommended.

Comment: -v only shows the link command, it doesn't make the error messages any clearer.  Pretty hard to guess why it refuses to tell you what symbols it could not find, smells like an stderr redirection problem.  Or maybe we need to see the link command ;)

Comment: It is telling me what symbols it cannot find, but am trying to accomplish the -v invocation as recommended.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest is a plain `VERBOSE=1 make` rather than just `make` (in case you use make).

The output is something like this:

```
VERBOSE=1 make      
[100%] Linking C executable example
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/example.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -rdynamic CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.c.o  -o example 
make[2]: Leaving directory '../c-examples/cmake/build'
[100%] Built target example
make[1]: Leaving directory '../c-examples/cmake/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start ../c-examples/cmake/build/CMakeFiles 0
```

You see that's `cc` is invoked here. In your case, you are using `clang` (it could have been `gcc` as well).

Let's assume you have done something like `sudo update-alternatives --config cc` - or any other way in which you organize symbolic links on your OS - to have `clang` as your default compiler. Now, if you just type `cc -v` you will see that it will show `version` information. You rather want to ask the linker to be verbose. That's done through `-Wl` or `-Xlinker`.

In your case, something like this `CMakeLists.txt` will give ample information:

```
# Note that this is an older cmake version, use target_link_options if available
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

# Project name (in this case a simple C project where the math dep is "forgotten")
project(mathdep_example)

# Not your situation, but in case you have a different linker
# set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--verbose")

# Clang passes flags through to the linker (likely ld) by
# set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Xlinker -v")

# Clang passing flags to the linker (likely ld) AND using -v itself to show how it calls the linker
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Xlinker -v -v")

# The final executable
add_executable(example main.c)

# In case you want also verbose compilation steps
target_compile_options(example PRIVATE -v)
```

Observe that `-v` occurs two times in the linker flags. The first preceded by `-Xlinker` will be passed to the linker (likely `ld`). The second is an option to `clang` itself at the linker step. Note, that `clang` still tells you to add `-v` even if you actually did so. This might be considered a bug...

In your case I would check what kind of `.o` and `.a` files you are using. It sounds like they are not for your architecture. Use `file`:

```
file object_file.o
file archive_file.a
```

Comment: I will try this as soon as I can.  Unfortunately a very critical issue is demanding my attention.  Yes, it is an ld issue, so it is not the compiler.  I will therefore try your -Wl or -Xlinker advice, and verbose.

Comment: I simply added this line: set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--verbose") to my cmakelists.txt file in the place you suggested and built. In the results, this line is now new: ld: unknown option: --verbose, and also these lines (the original link error info) are now missing:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Image::createImage(int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: VERBOSE=1 does give extensive info on what goes on during compilation, but does not provide any additional regarding the link process.

Comment: I suppose you have already added the `Xlinker -v` to your linker flags? Note that e.g. `gcc` or variants thereof will require a `-Wl` flag to pass to the linker. In your case I think you use `clang`, so it should be `Xlinker`. Then you can pass `-v` to the linker.

Comment: Just put your complete output with `VERBOSE=1 make` in a gist. And also return the results of `file *.o` and `file *.a`. You'll be helped in no time!

Comment: Note also that the message comes from clang `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`. However, it is complaining about the **linker**, which is probably just `ld`. It says that you can see how it calls the linker by just adding `-v` as command to **clang**.

Comment: I think that's what I am trying to do, what you said in your last comment.  You said "by just adding -v as command to clang".  That's all my question is about really.  But I don't know how to actually do that.  Could you be more specific?  I'm a rookie at building from command line, but use Xcode and Android Studio a lot.

Comment: I have a very simple cmakelists.txt file, and each time I compile and link I do so from inside a build folder I create.  Inside it I type 'cmake ..' and hit return, and then type 'make' and hit return.  The latter command compiles and links the app.  By the way I added a little more info to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200942/discussion-between-anne-van-rossum-and-alyoshak).